# Database magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

when i install magento 1.9.2 get error

```
Error in file: "C:\localhost\magento-192\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogRule\sql\catalogrule_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.1-1.6.0.2.php" - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'website_ids'; check that column/key exists
```

.  I tried several times without success. 
i think MySQL server run import slow. 
so i want file database-simple.sql.

Answer (score 1):

Simply drop the database and recreate. Magento will do the rest by itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/50239)

Comment: This is the solution, Magento create tables when installation process occurs. Magento shows this kind of errors whenever installation process left incomplete or php execution limit exceeds.
Magento saves modules list in a table which also saves module version. This problem can also be rectified by recreating the database. Magento will create all tables again.
Or drop `catalogrule` record from `core_resource` table.

Comment: when i install again get error  ***The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.***

Comment: @xanka Check if there is a file called **maintenance.flag** in your magento root. If so Delete it.